# Android OCR app : Tesseract dictionary

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm developping an Android application that takes a photo and translate that into text. I'm using tesseract 3 on windows.

I've managed to get most of the translation working correctly (after doing rescaling, binarization, enhancement) but some character are still not translated as it should be (ri -> m, le -> Ie, etc.).

To correct this, I was thinking about forcing tesseract to look into my language dictionary (french in my case) and use the most likely word to do the translatation. When I opened the french dictionary, I've been surprised to see every english words as well.

Is there a way to force tesseract to find the most likely word in the appropriate language ?

Also, I've not found many android code sample online and I am not sure I'm doing the most efficient of image preprocessing. This is what I'm currently doing, do you know how I could improve this even more ?

```
photo = WriteFile.writeBitmap(Scale.scale(ReadFile.readBitmap(bitmap), 3, 3));
photo = WriteFile.writeBitmap(AdaptiveMap.backgroundNormMorph(ReadFile.readBitmap(photo)));

photo = WriteFile.writeBitmap(Binarize.otsuAdaptiveThreshold(ReadFile.readBitmap(photo))); 
photo = WriteFile.writeBitmap(Enhance.unsharpMasking(ReadFile.readBitmap(photo), 3, (float) 0.5));
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT : For instance, this is the kind of results I have
[image: Photo of document]
[image: Result photo]

and the text result :

> Les actions sociales
>
> Les actions sociales regroupent les activités
>   suivantes: Heureux évenements + Aide handicap + Aide scolarité + aide
>   étudiante + Aide de secours, Malgré un nombre de bénéﬁciaires plus
>   important et un coat moyen par activité plus éleve qu'en 2012, Ie
>   budget 2013 alloué couvre largement les besoins d’ou l'excédent
>   constaté La C.F.T.C. ne peut que regretter la suppression en 2013 de
>   I‘activité «abonnement enfant» car son ﬁnancement aurait pu étre
>   couvert par l'excédent constaté

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, I need to scan small text(Textsize nearly 8 to 10sp) from the hard copy(hard copy like current bills,etc...). I am using this github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr Project. How to scan smaller text ?I am struck here.Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract has user.dawg file in which you can add words you want to add to its dictionary.

But what I would do is run the output trough additional checks. Write a program that splits the text by space, removes punctuation then checks every word in your dictionary - if the word is an exact match then this is the real word, if not then  compare the word with others using [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance.

I assume your dictionary will be a database so you could do other clever things, you can just write a query that searches the exact word (obviously), but when the word is not found use the [LIKE operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) in SQL to find similar words in a fashion chosen by you (for example all the words that start with the same letter) so you run your Levenstein distance only on words that start with the same letter (or words that look like your word in a way you have chosen) and thus saving unnecessary comparisons.